# Rating system for many-to-many competitions

Tags: ranking

I have some abstract sport, where for each player his/her `rating` (some number) is known. Then players participate in competition, and the scoreboard is made, placing each player at some place. I need to develop or find any system that can recalculate rating for each player based on his/her previous rating and their place at competition. I know about [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system), but I can't come up with an idea to make it suit my need (Elo rating is for competitions where players compete head-to-head). Is there anything to adapt for me or any ideas I can use?

Comment: How players compete against each other if not head-to-head? Is it like racing, where number of participants compete against each other and then finish in certain positions? I think the dynamics and the nature of the abstract sport you are mentioning is important for us to answer this question.

Comment: i think that question is too abstract. What is exactly wrong with Elo, and what do you want to achieve with your rating system? Also, take a look at F1 points system. It just gives number of points for positions at the end of each race

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in use (more than in development), you should give a try to [**rankade**](https://rankade.com), our skill based ranking system.

Opposite to **Elo** and **Glicko**  (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison)), rankade can manage any kind of match (one-on-one, faction vs. faction (two teams, which may be asymmetrical),
**multiplayer**, multi-faction, cooperative games, single player games, and so on), so you can insert *one* match with *Alice 5, Bob 4, Chris 3* (an more, up to 30 factions) output.

Comment: Is the rankade algorithm, or anything similar, open source or with a similar licence? I need to use it for a separate program I am running as a project

Comment: The service is free but the algorithm is not in public domain, for the time being.